# Footnote citation with author, year and page number

Tags: footnotes

I have set up my bibliography and it is working. This is how I cite:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\textbf{{\large Disposition}}

blablablabla.\cite{corpore20}
\\\\
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{biblio} 

\end{document}
```

This generates a [1] in place of \cite{corpore20}. How can I change this, so that instead of [1] I get a ^1 which generates a footnote with the information Author. (1987), p. 78

Is this in any way possible?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: It is possible, iirc biblatex \fullfootcite will do it with the right config. I don't know what that config is however.

Comment: If you use `biblatex`, you can say `\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}` and then `\autocite[78]{corpore20}` to generate a footnote with that information. By default, this will use `biber` as the backend so the compilation sequence would be (pdf)LaTeX -> Biber -> (pdf)LaTeX rather than a BibTeX run. If that's a problem, add `backend=bibtex` to the package options but Biber is recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `biblatex`, you can say

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
```

and then `\autocite[78]{corpore20}` to generate a footnote with that information. By default, this will use `biber` as the backend so the compilation sequence would be (pdf)LaTeX -> Biber -> (pdf)LaTeX rather than a BibTeX run. If that's a problem, add `backend=bibtex` to the package options but Biber is recommended.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\begin{document}
  \autocite[45]{westfahl:space}
\end{document}
```

[image: author-year style footcites]

Comment: it worked (I put backend=bibtex as a package option). thank you very much!